# Generate unique numbers based on a table's primary key, to be used as an external reference

Tags: java, unique-key

I need to generate a number, based on the primary key of an table, which will be used as an external reference (e.g. to label a product, or generate a barcode).
The number will be stored on database and later used to retrieve the actual record it was derived from.
The number has to be of a fixed length, say max 8 characters to minimize the length of the barcode.

Are there any Java APIs I can use to generate this number?

The solution need not imperatively derive the number form the primary key; I only need to ensure it will be unique across all records.

I need a programmatic Java solution; not a database-tied one.

Thanks,
Shehzaad

Comment: It is not possible, without knowing what the primary key is, to come up with a solution that is based on the primary key. Please specify the problem better.

Comment: Isn't the primary key such a number?

Comment: You really need to be more specific here. I read your question twice and really can't figure out what you're trying to do with the information you provided. Please edit soon, or your question will very likely be closed.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to generate a number, based on the primary key

is inconsistent with

> The solution need not imperatively derive the number form the primary key;

but,

java.util.UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[] bytes) may be your friend.

There are better UUID generators out there which are easy to find with a little googling.